# Load View from XIb crashes

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, swift3, xib

I am loading a view using xib but it crashes always. I have tried different approaches available on net but still it crashes.I don't find any solution to deal with. I have attached code for reference [Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0xjj9w8bhqvgtv/Cart%204.zip?dl=0)

Comment: what was the crash message ?

Comment: EXE_BAD_ACCESS comes always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code and the problem is you would give your view class to file owner and according to it change IBOutlets and IBActions.

So first thing is Give 'CartView'to FileOwner and Remove it from View.

Then remove IBAction from gesture and IBOutlets from lbl and img then again assign which will be refer to filesowner.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load cart like this

```
private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CartView", bundle: bundle)
        let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        return nibView
    }
```

There is absolutely no problem with loading a view with that. The problem is You should not load a view inside the view's class.

you have to do it inside a ViewController. like this:

```
func loadCartView() -> UIView! {
        if let customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CartView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? CartView {
            customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return customView
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

**SWIFT3:**

```
func loadCartView() -> UIView! {
    if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CartView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CartView {
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return customView
    } else {
        return nil
     }
    }
```

Comment: Jason , just adding Cart class to File Owner worked for me. There is no need to add that in VIewController.

Comment: I saw your code. Its not good approach to load views outside viewController as subviews. @Krishnanunni also said the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is wrong. You have set the class as Cart for both xib and the view in storyboard.

Try loading the nib from the viewController and add it as subview. If you need the small view in storyboard as a container, just create an outlet and add the card view as subview to container.

Comment: I think this is more appropriate approach to load views from xib

Comment: Ok but what if I want to make an IBDesignable class. This way I have to subclass that from Storyboard.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set IBDesignable from xib. The images you set won't be reflected in IB

Comment: No I am talking about making class as IBDesignable and set it subclass in ViewController from Storyboard.